# String with white space being passed incorrectly in a Django template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have a variable called "Vintage White" that I am trying to pass to an attribute of an input element like so.

```
<input name={{ attribute_value }}>
```

What I expect is for the element to be rendered like this

```
<input name="Vintage White">
```

But instead I get this

```
<input name="Vintage" white>
```

How do I pass the entire string with white spaces to the input element so that I get my expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use quotation marks, otherwise the value will end before the first space of the `attribute_value`, so:

```
<input name="{{ attribute_value }}">
```